# Dash blurred part of the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Is it possible to dash the blurred part of the image?

Right now I am using **python** with **OpenCV**. I know only how to load images and display if the image is blurred.

My input is a blurred image:

[image: Import]

I would like to get:

[image: Export]

I do not have:
original/unblurred image.

Output can have still blurred parts but dashed.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: make a pattern of white dots on a black image the same size of your original image. Then binary-and / invert / etc... you original image with the pattern, using the same mask you used for blurring

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Nice point, however, I do not do blurring. My input is already a blurred image. So I need to recognize what part of the image is blurred. Then after that, I have to add a pattern of white dots as u mentioned. But I do not know how to find blurred parts :(

Comment: Then you have two bigger problems: 1) find the blurred parts, 2) recover the sharp shape

Comment: Only 1 :D. I do not need to sharp shape. (edited main post) "Output can have still blurred parts but dashed."

Comment: then the laplacian trick should work well enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try by computing the "Variance of the Laplacian" on parts of the image to detect the regions that have a low variation in greyscales (= assumed blurry) and which regions have a high variation in greyscale (= assumed non-blurry).

There is a nice tutorial on how to check if an image is blurry, it can be found [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)

There is also a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319918/whats-the-theory-behind-computing-variance-of-an-image) that explains the theory behind it.

It ain't a complete solution, but it might be a way to start.

Comment: Thanks! I have found out that tutorial. I was trying with this project https://github.com/WillBrennan/BlurDetection2 by WillBrennan. It is a ready solution for showing me blurred parts: http://prntscr.com/v0ko5s . I have added swap black and white: Now I have: http://prntscr.com/v0kq0w . So it is something! :)